# Android scrollview doesn't work - 1 main child linear layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

This is my code:
1 child, other relative layout elements are nested inside main one, so it makes 1 child for scroll view.

I am creating this for Nexus 7, but when I check it inside my HTC Desire HD scroll view doesn't work, it just cuts last "RelativeLayoutGerman".

Any ideas?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
        android:gravity="clip_vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMainHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bghead"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMainGerman"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutMainSlovenscina"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewMainGerman"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewMainLine3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/mainGerman"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#9B7D66" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMainSlovenscina"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutMainEnglish"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCategoriesDrinks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/mainSlovene"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#9B7D66" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewMainLine1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewTopLine2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/descrLine"
                android:src="@drawable/middleline" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTopLine2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewCategoriesDrinks"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/descrLine"
                android:src="@drawable/line_top" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMainEnglish"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutMainHeader"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="selectEnglish"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewMainEnglish"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutMainHeader"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/mainEnglish"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#9B7D66" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewMainLine3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewTopLine1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/middleline" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTopLine1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewMainEnglish"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/descrLine"
                android:src="@drawable/line_top" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem but I don't believe `RelativeLayout` has an `orientation` attribute. And why do you have that `TextView` set below another view if its parent layout is already positioned below a `View`?

Comment: I think the same thing could be achieved with LinearLayouts inside a scroll view.

Comment: codeMagic, I put it below so it doesn't overlap on different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `ScrollView` to a `LinearLayout` (You might need to remove the `android:fillViewport="true"` line) and then create a separate `ScrollView` inside the `LinearLayout`.

If you need something on the bottom of the page (assuming you're doing something similar to [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)) Here's a little trick that I found works.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:duplicateParentState="false" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="true" >



</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did that, and it works, but "android:fillViewport" doesn't fill anymore.

Comment: Hi, check my edited post. Put the things you need inside the ScrollView inside the ScrollView (and FrameLayout, not sure if that is completely necessary but I know that works) and then whatever needs to stick to the bottom of the page just goes in the outside linear layout.